# chmod seems to have no effect on php files or clarifying permissions handling

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, permissions, chmod

I recently switched from using .shtml files for my webpages to using .php files. After figuring out how PHP handles directories, everything seemed to work fine. That is until I realized file permissions don't seem to work the same with .php files as they do with .shtml files.

Problem: Certain php files in the web root should be inaccessible to the outside world, so the permission settings are set accordingly and `ls -l` reveals that the file's permission status is

```
-rwx------
```

Unfortunately, this file is still accessible to the world. However, denying users access to the file makes the file inaccessible to the world, though it doesn't autodirect to 403.php. Instead, a simple "Access denied" is displayed.

What's odd about this is that my permissions settings work as expected with my .shtml files. If I attempt to access test.shtml I am automatically redirected to mywebsite.com/403 as per my .htaccess settings.

This all leads to two questions:

1. How do I properly manage permissions for .php files?
2. Can I hardcode permissions within the .htaccess file?

Comment: Thanks @johnk for cleaning up my question and teaching SO etiquette at the same time!

Comment: If they should be "inaccessible to the outside world", they should not be under the webroot! However, based on the permissions shown here, I would guess that you probably have the PHP files owned by the httpd's user - PHP doesn't have any kind of magic powers to subvert the OS' permissions system. You can certainly deny access to certain files with .htaccess; but the better solutions is "don't put them in the web root - put them elsewhere on the filesystem(s)".

Comment: Thanks for the comment @TML, simply moving the aforementioned pages "above" the webroot is indeed the obvious and easiest solution. However, I am still perplexed why executing `chmod 700 file.shtml` prevents "groups" and "others" on the internet from accessing "file.shtml", while executing `chmod 700 file.php` does **not** prevent "groups" and "others" from accessing "file.php". Clearly, I am missing something fundamental!

Comment: Well, I don't have enough information about what you're doing to give a great answer, but here's what I just did locally:
* enabled both includes and php mods
* created /var/www/html/test.shtml with content http://ideone.com/Ezb78k
* ln -s /var/www/html/test.shtml
* sudo chown www-data.www-data test.shtml
* sudo chmod 0700 test.shtml

test.shtml and test.php work fine because the user Apache runs as (www-data) can read the file.

* sudo chown tml test.shtml


test.shtml and test.php both fail because the user Apache runs as (www-data) cannot read the file.